# Another Unparseable date with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a date (I get it from an Rss) in Java. This is my code

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, DD MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
Date myDate = myFormat.parse(myString);
```

Where myString is: `"Mon, 24 Nov 2014 00:20:41 +0000"`

Unfortunately all I get is a `"java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon, 24 Nov 2014 00:20:41 +0000" (at offset 0)"`

If I am not wrong, the format string must match the actual date-string. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `dd` instead of `DD`.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
D   Day in year     Number  189
d   Day in month    Number   10


SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
                                                 Locale.US);
String myString = "Mon, 24 Nov 2014 00:20:41 +0000";
Date myDate = myFormat.parse(myString);
System.out.println(myDate);
```

**Output on my machine:**

```
Mon Nov 24 01:20:41 CET 2014
```

Comment: Ahem. You almost got it. I mean: I had already caught (30 secs after posting) the dd instead of DD... What I was missing was the Locale.US! :-) Thank you!